# Example of coherent ring with finite self FP-Injective dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I need example of coherent ring with self FP-injective dimension less than or equal to n. 
This ring is called an n-FC-ring ?

Recall that the definition of coherent ring 
If R is a coherent if every finitely generated ideal is finitely presented.

Comment: Isn’t any field an example? Or why not, if not?

Comment: I'm looking for another example other than the field

Answer (score 0):

How about any group algebra $F[G]$ using a field $F$ and a finite abelian group $G$?

It is guaranteed to be Artinian and self-injective, which makes it coherent and (I suppose) have finite FP-injective dimension.